# Find functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}, n\ge 2$ such that $\nabla f(x)= 0$ and $x$ is local min but not global, and $x$ is saddle point

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

> Find functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}, n\ge 2$ such that $\nabla
>  f(x)= 0$ and $x$ is:
>
> a) local maximizer but not global
>
> b) saddle point
>
> c) global minimizer

c) this is the easiest, just pick $g(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^tAx$ for a definite matrix $A$ and thus it is convex because the second derivative is $A$, and $\nabla g(0)=0$ thus $0$ is a local minimizer. Since the function is convex, it is a global one

b) I'm thinking about $(x+y)^3$ which has derivative $3(x+y)^2$ which is $0$ at $0$, but it is also $0$ at the second derivative. So it may be that $0$ is not a minimizer. I'd say that indeed it isn't because at the direction $(0,1)$ we're dealing with $(y)^3$ which has a saddle point

a) This one is a bit trickier. I know that in one dimension, if I do something with sine such that the sine oscilates between smaller and smaller numbers each time, it has minimum and maximum points that are not global. For example, $x\sin(x)$. But how do make it work in two variables?

Comment: How do you **define** a saddle point? You can create a one dimensional polynomial to illustrate a?, c) and then ignore other variables to get an example.

Comment: @copper.hat I think my book supposes it is a point where the gradient is $0$ but it is not an extreme. If it's this, then I think my answer is right

Comment: Your answer is valid, but a more standard example might be $(x,y) \mapsto x^2-y^2$.

Comment: @copper.hat yes, just graphed to see how it looks. For a), I thought in one dimension, but I cannot simply say 'not think of this function is two dimensions depending only on $x$', that's 'cheating'.

Comment: Well, the $(x+y)^3$ is essentially one dimensional :-).

Comment: @copper.hat I meant that $x$ and $y$ should appear in the equation. $x\sin x$ works in one dimension but when I plot it in two dimensions with $x\sin (x+y)$ I get some things that don't look like maximum points